# Measure of the boundary of an open set of finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing the Lebesgue measure of an open set and its closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28052/comparing-the-lebesgue-measure-of-an-open-set-and-its-closure)

Given an open set in $\Bbb R^2$ of finite Lebesgue measure, why does the boundary of its closure have measure zero?

Comment: This is false, isn't it? Consider the inside of a positive-measure Jordan curve.

Comment: You can take a look at here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25993/sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-boundary.

Comment: Or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/185950/6179).